# What kind of association for this circumstance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm new to RoR, and I'm trying to create my first association within my app between an Order model, and a star key that represents all of the users who have starred that particular order.

I was originally thinking of using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for this, but that doesn't make sense given that there aren't many stars coming from the one user to one order.

With that said, I've really confused myself and could use a little bit of direction. Perhaps a simple migration file would send me down the right path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming users can "star" more than one order, then you do indeed want `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You can readily enforce that any one user has only one relationship to any one order.

Answer (score 1):

I would indeed create an in between table referencing both Order and User, as an order has many users that keyed the order, and a user can key many orders...

```
rails g migration CreateOrderUsers order:references user:references
```

Your order_users model becomes

```
belongs_to: order
belongs_to: user
```

Then put in your order model

```
has_many :order_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many users, through: :order_users
```

And in your user model

```
has_many :order_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many orders, through: :order_users
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't this technically a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association then?

Comment: depends... if you ever want to add an extra field to the "in between" table, then you'd better construct it as I mentioned. If you never ever want to add a field to the in-between, you might use a has_and_belongs_to_many... I personally never use it, just to leave the opening...